# Clarity between Pointer-to-Pointer, Value-of-Pointed address and 2D-Array access

Tags: c++, c

Can someone set the path straight on the disparities between these ubiquitous, as It can get a bit mind blowing.

For example if I have a *2D* array such as `rec[3][2]`, the following access means the same;

```
rec[0][0] = **rec
rec[i][0] = **(rec + i)
*(*(rec + i) + j) = rec[i][j]
```

If this is the case then what are the meaning of these:

```
#include <stdio.h>
double *recptr[3];
int i=1;

main()
{
 double n1=12.0;
 doublw n2=3.4;

 recptr[0]= &n1;
 recptr[1]= &n2;

 printf("Amt: %.2f\n", **(recptr + i));
}
```

What is `**(recptr + i)`, Is this access to 2D pointer or ponter-to-pointer reference?

```
foo(ptr2ptr)double **ptr2ptr;
{
 int i=1, j=0;
 if(**(ptr2ptr +i) > **(ptr2ptr + j))
 {
  double *tmp= *(recptr +i);
 }
}
```

Again what is the difference between `*(recptr +i)` and `**(ptr2ptr +i)`?! is the later also 2D access or access to pointer-2-ponter reference and the earlier the object pointed to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is array name a pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double *recptr[3];
```

This creates an array of 3 pointers to double `(double*)`.
Now, in the `main()`, we have double `n1 = 12.0f` and double `n2 = 3.4f`.

Now we assign the address of `n1 (&n1)` to `recptr[0]` (First element of the array which just happens to point to doubles, so now it points to an address of a double (our n1) which is ok.) -> Please do note this is NOT a reference (in theory). We are taking the address of n1.

We do the same thing with n2, so now `recptr[1]` is a pointer that points to the address of n2.

Now we print `**(recptr + i)` -> This means the following:

We take the address of the first element of the array (recptr evaluates to the address of the aray), we offset this address by i (which just happens to be 1). Now please do note that we don't move 1 byte further, we move `sizeof(double*)` bytes further.

Now, we dereference this position `*(recptr + i)` which is (address of first element + `sizeof(double*)` bytes) away and what do we see ? Well, it's a pointer to a double (Or in other words, it's just an address of n2). So we need to dereference yet again to actually see the value that this particular pointer points to, hence `**(recptr + i)`.

So, the first dereference just gives us the correct "cell" of our recptr array but in that cell, there's a pointer to a double, so in order to get to it's value, we need to dereference yet again.

(We then indeed print 3.40 since it's address happens to live in the second cell of recptr array.)